CDFA Calculation in Charts
I'm trying to find the accurate formula which is used on a 2D and sometimes 3D approach that calculates the Altitude at which you have to be at a specific distance for a CDFA. Using trigonometry yields a result which is off by 20ft sometimes even more. Is the curvature of the Earth used for this calculations? If you can provide a solution for this example which gives an exact number(if possible) or a closer result from my calculations will be appreciated. I'm starting to believe they round up the values published in the charts.
Ex.
LAX RWY 24R

My calculation to find 2,200' at 6.3nm from rwy threshold:
TDZE= 122'
TCH= 55'
Distance= 6.3nm
Alt= x
x= tan(3) * (6.3 * 6076.12)
x= 2006.1465' + 122' + 55'
ALT at 6.3nm = 2183.1465'... I'm off by roughly 27ft.
Any insight will be appreciated, thank you in advance.
Regards,
mabg

Instrument approaches do include the curvature of the earth in their considerations. At 6.3 nautical miles this is something like 30 feet.
But there are various types of rounding going on, too. Most importantly in this case, the 6.3 nautical miles you're relying on is the sum of 0.9, 0.8, and 4.6, which are all rounded to the nearest tenth of a nautical mile. The FAF is defined as being at 8.3 DME from the localizer, which is not exactly 6.3 from the runway threshold.

It is 6.36 NM from the threshold, which proves your point.

Your maths is correct, though I think you mean you’re 17 feet off, not 27 feet?
Your assumption about rounding is likely correct as well:
Practical Considerations
When considering the chart from a pilot's perspective, especially during a relatively fast approach, a discrepancy of 17 feet at 6.3 NM out is negligible. This minor difference does not impact the accuracy or safety of the approach.
Chart vs Actual Final Approach Path Altitude-Distances
The altitude shown on the chart may differ slightly from the altitude at which the aircraft is actually flying along the final approach path. For example, while the aircraft may be closer to 2183 feet at 6.3 NM, when the pilot cross-checks this against the chart, seeing 2200 feet is close enough. Given that the aircraft is likely descending at around 600-900 feet per minute ($=$ 15 feet per second), this minor difference is not operationally significant.
Rounding Benefits
Pilots are very busy during the approach phase, and having altitudes rounded to the nearest 10 feet simplifies their workload. The aircraft’s instruments typically display altitudes in increments of 10 or 20 feet, so rounding helps in quickly cross-referencing with charted altitudes without requiring unnecessary mental effort.
Altimeter Settings and Altitude Discrepancies
It's also important to note that altimeter settings are typically adjusted to the nearest hPa1, which can introduce a difference of about 27 feet per hPa in indicated altitude. This is another reason why minor discrepancies such as 17ft does not matter in practice. Furthermore, temperature variations can slightly affect the true altitude at a given distance on a final approach path. These small variations are accounted for in the design of charts, which is why rounding is both practical and operationally sound.

To properly answer your question, I believe your mathematical calculations are correct i.e. you are probably being more accurate and precise than the chart. The Earth's curvature will be negligible over 6.3nm. Additionally, if the approach involves an Instrument Landing System (ILS), the glide slope is defined by radio waves, which travel in a straight line relative to the curvature of the Earth. This means that the curvature does not affect the glide slope calculations. The minor discrepancies you observe are more likely due to rounding or simplifications in the charting process rather than any significant geometric considerations.

1.  Some countries use inches of mercury rather an hPa increments, such as: USA, Canada, Mexico and Japan. 0.01 inHg = 10 feet of altitude change 

Don't forget that there is are slight variables due to glide slope antenna placement on the aircraft and height of landing gear.
